# Why “Request Failed” alert on iPad?

Tags: support

I was trying to do some minor voting and commenting on my **iPad** and each time I tried to complete the action, I obtained the following alert:

> Request Failed.
>
> Could not perform this request with your account.
> Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta.

This happened here and on SE Biology. I logged out and back. No improvement.

I then logged onto my **laptop** and was able to operate as normal.

So I am posting this question on meta, as requested (although more in hope than expectation).

Comment: Would you happen to be using the iOS app?

Comment: @Laurel Thanks — that was it. I’d removed the app from my phone ages ago, but didn’t realize it was the app (rather than a bookmark) on my iPad, which I use much less frequently. I’ll make this into an answer when I have a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a comment from @Laurel I discovered that *I still had a Stack Exchange app on my iPad*, and that *removing this and using the web version solved the problem.*

I should have thought of this because of recent notices regarding the demise of the app, but my reaction to those was abhorrence of the jargon used rather than reflection on the information.

One point to note is that the icon for the app is the same as the icon on the bookmark that one can download to one’s home screen. I had the latter on my iPhone, and had to check that I had not done the same on the iPad.

Comment: >> *but my reaction to those was abhorrence of the jargon used* << Oh come now, the term "sunsetted" seems far more approachable, and easier to understand for users such as myself,  than the actual jargon used by developers,  engineers, programmers and the like. Many a time I had to search the meaning of an acronym, e.g., UI and UX.  Not everyone works in IT.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Decommission", which is in the original post, has been in use for almost 100 years. "Sunsetting" is an example of one of the worst kinds of business-speak. I was horrified when I first heard an academic colleague use it, and find it especially abhorrent on this list. And I don't use acronyms. One of the first rules of communication is to avoid them if possible and to define them if not. Who do you think has been going through all the posts regarding Cambridge Grammar's NP and changing them to "noun phrase"? In IT this philosophy is an integral part of designing computer interfaces.

Comment: You may not use acronyms (and I thank you) but its use is typical of IT jargon. Meanwhile, I'll note with interest that *sunset*, meaning to *phase out*, is used in politics and business and appears to originate in N.America. So our friend Dan Bron, who is American, used it appropriately. And there I thought he was using it in clever and original way to express the discontinuation of a programme.